# How to make a one to zero or many relationship in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, cardinality

I have a `table` `users` and another `table` `orders`, and I am considering to be a `one` to `zero or many` relationship because `one` `user` can have `zero or many` `orders`.

I just simply can´t find how to do this in `MySQL Workbench`. If I uncheck `NOT NULL` for the `foreign key`( primary key of users ) in the orders table, it gives me `one or zero to many`, and that´s not what I want.

Please help me what I am doing wrong as I have been trying for so long to get this work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confused about how a one to zero or more relationship is reprented in a relational database.  If a certain user has no orders, then there would be no records in the `orders` table which refer back to that user.  This is the zero case.  The case of a one-to-one relationship would be a single user with a single referring order, and one-to-many is similar.

It does not make much sense to me to have order records which are not associated with any user.  Most likely, this would be an interruption to your business/fulfillment process anyway, and you would not invite such records to occur.

Comment: I am still confused honestly. is then the other way around a one or zero to many relationship?

Comment: You find out the relationship when you join.  If joining a certain user to orders yields a zero order count, then the relationship is one to zero.  Zero to many from either side makes no sense; there has to be a record to start with.  One to zero from the orders side also makes no sense, because it would imply a stranded order not belonging to anyone.

Comment: okay so probably still one to zero or many. And how to draw that in MySQL Workbench as that was my initial question?

Comment: I think you are over analyzing things.  Please update your question and describe the business problem you are modeling, and someone can give a suggested schema.